# APK rejected from play store due to ''All Files Access Permission''

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app which is developed for both Android and iOS. Recently from play store apk rejected due to **All Files Access Permission** Which we then remove **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission and re-uploaded to play store but still rejected. In this app we use camera to take pictures and uploaded to server, create PDF using byte[] and then save in the app specific storage and display using PDF viewer. We use Xamarin.Essential for both take pictures and display PDFs.

PDF creation

```
            if (resList != null)
            {
                using (var memstream = new MemoryStream(resList))
                {
                    string dateTimePart = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss");
                    string fileName = "bonus_" + dateTimePart + ".pdf";
                    var filePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    string filePathWithName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
                    await DependencyService.Get<ISaveFile>().SaveFiles(filePathWithName, resList, filePath);

                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                    {
                        await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
                        {
                            Title = fileName,
                            File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePathWithName)
                        });
                    }
                    else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IPDFPreviewProvider>().TriggerPreview(filePathWithName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Custom class for save PDFs in Android section

```
   public class AndroidSaveFile : ISaveFile
    {
        public async Task<string> SaveFiles(string filename, byte[] bytes, string filePath)
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Storage permission!", "To save files, you need the storage permissions.", "OK");
                }

                status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<StoragePermission>();
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Storage Denied!", "Can not access storage on this device. Please check the permission and try again.", "OK");
            }

            return filename;
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.customer" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="26" android:versionName="2.5">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <permission android:name="com.customer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.customer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:label="NAME" android:allowBackup="false" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:icon="@drawable/iconLaunch">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.customer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/noti_icon_c" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/fcm" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationAccentColor.DEFAULT" android:value="FF04b2b5" />;
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: how about remove every drafts, replace every track (alpha, beta and production etc) where the non-compliant version is active.

Comment: done.but no luck

Comment: check android documents about manage all files https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage